# How to return a reponse in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API JWT authentication when statuscode is 401

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I developed an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, and I'm using JWT.

I try to return a response when status code = 401, but I can not figure out.

I want to return a response as shown here:

```
response.ResultCode = 401;
response.ResultMessage = "Invalid token, please call Login() method."
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JWT bearer authentication, you can hook a handler to the `JwtBearerEvents.OnChallenge` callback like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                //other options....
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
                        {
                            // Write to the response in any way you wish
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid token, please call Login() method.");
                        });    
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }                        
                };
            });
```

Comment: I tested but not work. I added options.Events like your code. And i tried any method in api without token in swagger. It gives shows 401

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like below.

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnChallenge = context =>
                  {

                      context.HandleResponse();
                      context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                      context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                      var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                      {
                          ResultCode = "2",
                          Message = "Invalid Token"
                      });

                      return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                  },

            };
```